# Indian passport holder on a US visa visiting the Canadian side of the Niagara Falls

Tags: visas, usa, transit, canada, indian-citizens

I and my wife are on tour currently in US holding US visa for 10 years.  We hold Indian passports and we are Indian citzens.

We want to visit the Canadian side of Niagara and have to cross from US side to Canadian side.  Can I obtain a transit visa at the bridge for few hours' visit?

Answer (score 5):

If you enter Canada to visit, there is no difference between "a few hours" and "a few months". You would need to get the same permission in either case.

It's unclear from your question whether you are a *permanent resident* in the US, and this makes a difference for entry into Canada. US permanent residents can enter Canada for a visit without any additional documentation (just passport plus US permanent resident visa or green card). However, if you are not a US permanent resident, then as an Indian passport holder you will need a visitor visa for Canada.

Comment: The provisions you are referring to apply only to US *permanent* residents, not all "US residents".

Comment: US permanent residents do not need a passport to go to Canada unless they're flying.  The only document they need to cross the land border in both directions is the green card.  But anyone who is inside the US with a 10-year visa -- or indeed any sort of US visa -- is not a permanent resident.